# hangman game in python after trying to exit after playing one round

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I play one round of the game and select the option to quit, the game finishes, BUT, if I play a second round and try to quit, the game continues and the user is prompted to enter a guess again, instead of terminating the game.

It seems to be stuck in a loop.

Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
def core_game():

    def init_hangman():
        hangman = []

        for x in range(7):
            hangman.append([" "] * 7)
        hangman[0][0] = "_"
        hangman[0][1] = "_"
        hangman[0][2] = "_"
        hangman[1][3] = "|"
        return hangman

    hangman = init_hangman()

    def print_hangman():
        for x in hangman:
            print(str.join("", x))

    def get_input(guess):
            your_guess = input(guess)
            if your_guess in guessed_letters:
                print("You already guessed that letter!")
                return get_input(guess)
            elif your_guess.isalpha() and len(your_guess) == 1:
                return your_guess
            else:
                print("Please guess a single letter!")
                return get_input(guess)

    words_list = ["monkey", "cow"]
    city_list = ["Amarillo", "Houston"]
    lists = ["animals", "cities"]
    random_list = randint(0,1)
    random_word = randint(0,1)
    if lists[random_list] == "cities":
        rand_list = city_list
    elif lists[random_list] == "animals":
        rand_list = words_list
    word = rand_list[random_word]
    guessed = ""
    guessed_letters = []
    hang = 6
    Cont = True

    for letter in word:
        guessed += "-"

    print("\n\n\nWELCOME TO HANGMAN!")    
    print("The category is: ", lists[random_list])
    print("The secret word: ", guessed, "is", len(guessed), "letters")

    while Cont:
        your_guess = get_input("\nEnter your guess: ")
        if your_guess in word.lower():           
            for x in range(len(word)):
                if word[x].lower() == your_guess.lower():
                    guessed = guessed[:x] + word[x] + guessed[x+1:]
            guessed_letters.append(your_guess)
            print("\nThe secret word: ", guessed)
            if guessed.lower() == word.lower():
                print("\n\nCongratulations, you guessed the word!")
                play_again = input("\nWould you like to play again?(y/n) ")
                if play_again == "y" or play_again == "yes":
                    core_game()
                else:
                    Cont = False

        else:
            hang -= 1
            guessed_letters.append(your_guess)
            print("\nGuessed letters: ", guessed_letters)
            if hang == 5:
                hangman[2][3] = "O"
                print_hangman()
                print(guessed)
            elif hang == 4:
                hangman[3][3] = "|"
                print_hangman()
                print(guessed)
            elif hang == 3:
                hangman[3][2] = "-"
                print_hangman()
                print(guessed)
            elif hang == 2:
                hangman[3][4] = "-"
                print_hangman()
                print(guessed)
            elif hang == 1:
                hangman[4][2] = "/"
                print_hangman()
                print(guessed)
            elif hang == 0:
                hangman[4][4] = "\\"
                print_hangman()
                print("Game Over!")
                print("The word was: ", word)
                play_again = input("Would you like to play again?(y/n) ")
                if play_again == "y" or play_again == "yes":
                    core_game()
                else:
                    Cont = False


core_game()
```

The main function is core_game() and this is called when the program is run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you get help much faster (-1)

Comment: To be more precise... you could for instance make this example 10 rows, verify your example still gives error and ask the question again.

Comment: OK, I will try to narrow it down. Thanks for the info Anton

Comment: I think there is an error in the logic inside the main flow of the while loop.  Good game though- well done on writing all this on your own!  Most first years in college can't even print "Hello World" so getting up to speed with lists, strings, functions etc. will really stand to you!

Comment: @srattigan Yes a very valid point. Looks like you are doing great. Have a look at **dictionaries** too as those are essential in basic programming.

Comment: Hi, my post was deleted by a moderator, so I did a new one that (I hope) shows why this is happening- included a screenshot as well.  It's a common enough mistake that I've seen many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay- yes, I like the game- played it in the browser at trinket.io

Then I walked through an entire game [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html).  Use this to debug your code, step by step and you can view all of the variables, lists etc. as well as enter input and view output.

The reason that your game is repeating is because:

1) In the function **core_game** you have the following code:

```
if play_again == "y" or play_again == "yes":
    core_game()
```

This means that when you select yes after the first game, you are opening another "instance" of the function- you can see this if you trace through the code.  You can also see this in the screenshot below (f19).

2) after you play the second game (remember that the first instance is still open) and select "n", this causes the "Cont" variable to change to False, but only in the second instance.  The "while" is closed then, and the code goes back to the first instance where Cont is still True.  You can also see both instances in the screenshot, and the state of each value of "Cont". The closed frame is "greyed out".

3) The program resumes in the first instance of the core_game at the start of the while loop, and the user is prompted to enter a guess.

This is difficult to see until you trace through the code, but I have included a snapshot here where you can (I hope) see what I mean.

[image: Snapshot of game state after entering "no" for second game]

So the issue is that you are calling the function from within itself.

Consider something more like this:

```
def core_game():
    print("I was called")


while Cont:
    ans = ("Do you wish to play a game? (Y/N)")
    if ans[0].lower() == "y":  # works for Y, y, Yup, Yeah, Yes etc.
        core_game()
    else:
        Cont = False
```

PS
there are other really good reference sources out there, such as [this](https://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf) as well.

Never give up- you'll find the step-thru really handy, and you might try Rice Universities MOOC on Coursera at some later stage.

Comment: OK, thanks again! So from my understanding, I need to change Cont to false before starting the function again so that when i return to the first instance the While loop will be false and I wont be stuck in the loop and the game will close properly. Thank you so much for the insight. Is there a better way to go about this though, such as put a sys.exit() function in instead of changing the value of Cont to false, or is that the best way to go about closing the game?

Comment: I'm afraid it will mean a bit more re-structuring of the code, but I've included a sample above that will avoid this error.  Essentially take the call for a new game OUT of the core_game itself.

Btw, if this satisfies your query, I'd much appreciate if you accept this as the "correct answer"  :)  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated! Answered my question plus some.